# Unknown field in logfile

Tags: java, logging

I have simple `Java` logger created by :

```
private void createLoggerA(String fileName) 
    {
        try
        {
            Level logLevel= Level.ALL;
            logger = Logger.getLogger("LOGGER");
            logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
            logger.setLevel(logLevel);

            makeDirs(fileName);

            LogFormatterA lf =  new LogFormatterA();

            File f=new File(fileName); 
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
            fh.setFormatter(lf);
            fh.setLevel(logLevel);
            logger.addHandler(fh);

            ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
            ch.setFormatter(lf);
            ch.setLevel(logLevel);
            logger.addHandler(ch);

        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If i do logging:

```
l.fine("bla bla");
```

in outpuut I have :

```
2016.03.21 12:28:35.641 1 . FINE:   bla bla
```

What does number 1 between date and `. FINE` means:

...641 **1** . FINE...

Comment: What is `LogFormatterA` and what is your logging system ?

Comment: Who is object `l` ? And if its class is made by you, can you provide the method `fine`?

Comment: What is logger pattern defined in lo4j.xml file